# Powershell Generate array from string with in quotes

Tags: powershell

i have below input as string

```
[string]$str = "'str01' 'str02' 'str03' 'str04' 'str05'"
```

want output as array

```
$arr[0] = str01
$arr[1] = str02
$arr[2] = str03
$arr[3] = str04
$arr[4] = str05
```

Any help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code? What is the purpose of that output? Is it just to have the pixels in the console? Did you try the [-split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
[string]$str = "'str01' 'str02' 'str03' 'str04' 'str05'"
[string[]]$arr = $str.Split(" ").Replace("'","")
$arr
```

output

```
str01
str02
str03
str04
str05
```

Comment: but if we have space in-between string like "'str 01' 'str 02' 'str 03' 'str 04' 'str 05'"

Comment: @mclayton answered this.

Comment: [regex]::matches($str,'(?<=\'').+?(?=\'')').value   | Where { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned in a comment to @AliReza's answer that you might also have spaces in your data.

Without knowing the full spec for your data format it's going to be hard to give a complete answer that works for all cases, but one other option might be to split on apostrophes and then take alternate items:

```bsh
PS> $str = "'str 01' 'str 02' 'str 03' 'str 04' 'str 05'"
PS> $i = 0; $str.Split("'") | where-object { $i % 2 -eq 1; $i++ }
str 01
str 02
str 03
str 04
str 05
```

If your data might also contain apostrophes then you're going to need to give an example that includes them so we can see how they're escaped in the data vs matched as delimiters.